# Sympy: prevent a subscripted symbol to be evaluated

Tags: sympy, maxima

Given a symbol `s`, which ultimately will be an Array, I want to define the following expression

```
A = Array([-s[1]/2, s[0]/2])
```

but I'd like `A` to be evaluated only when I compute some other expressions containing it, because `s` changes over time. I tried

```
A = UnevaluatedExpr(Array([-s[1]/2,s[0]/2]))
```

but I got the error `TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable`, which make me think that some evaluation is performed on `s`.

Thanks for your patience, I'm just learning Sympy and I'm used to [Maxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/index.html) where this kind of construct is straightforward. To be more precise, with Maxima the full working code I'm trying to *translate* into Sympy is (in Maxima everything is a symbol, colon is the assignment operator, `ev` forces evaluation with custom values, the dot before `diff` is the vector scalar product):

```
A: [-s[2],s[1]]/2; /* define A in terms of subscripted symbols */
P1: [x1,y1];
P2: [x2,y2];
segment: P1+t*(P2-P1); /* --> [t*(x2-x1)+x1,t*(y2-y1)+y1] */
factor(integrate(ev(A,s=segment).diff(segment,t),t,0,1)); /* integrates the scalar product of A evaluated over segment and the derivative of segment */
```

##### Follow up

Thanks to Oscar answer I was able to come up with a working Sympy translation of the above Maxima code (improvements are welcomed!):

```
from sympy import *

def dotprod(*vectors): # scalar product, is there a built in better way?
    return sum(Mul(*x) for x in zip(*vectors))

s = IndexedBase('s')
A = Array([-s[1]/2,s[0]/2])

t,x1,y1,x2,y2 = symbols('t x1 y1 x2 y2')
P1 = Array([x1,y1])
P2 = Array([x2,y2])
segment = P1 + t * (P2-P1)

dotprod(A.subs(s,segment),segment.diff(t)).integrate((t,0,1)).factor()
```

Apart from the `IndexedBase` *magic* the structure of the code in Maxima and Sympy is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want. It's possible that your problem is better approached in a different way rather than using `Array`. In any case a direct answer to your question is that you can use `IndexedBase` to make a subscriptable symbol:

```
In [1]: s = IndexedBase('s')

In [2]: A = Array([-s[1]/2, s[0]/2])

In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
⎡-s[1]   s[0]⎤
⎢──────  ────⎥
⎣  2      2  ⎦
```

Comment: I updated my question with the Maxima code I'm trying to translate, I hope it clarifies what I want to do.